# How to Stop/Wait a Thread and then Resume/Restart it later

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I am running a service in the background which is also binded to an activity to provide some data results to the view.
So My service is running in the background and I am binding the service when my activity starts and unbinding it when it closes irrespective of my background service which is running constantly.
And this service is first triggered when my activity starts the first time.

Now I have created two threads in the service. One is used for the background work. Other thread "displayThread" is used to fetch and push data to the activity.

Now my display thread is like this:

```
Thread displayThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                executeDisplayQueue();
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                displayThread.interrupt();
            }
        }
});
```

So when my activity starts my service starts, and I am starting both the threads:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Creating Service......");
    thread.start();
    displayThread.start();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Service is created.");
}
```

Now what I want is that when I am unbinding my service when activity closes my "displayThread" stops or pauses and it restarts or resumes when again activity starts which calls rebind() function.

```
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    super.onUnbind(intent);
    // Stop/Pause/Wait my displayThread here
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    super.onRebind(intent);
    // Restart/Resume my displayThread here
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "trying to check display thread");
}
```

Please help me here as I tried a lot of things.
Now displayThread.wait() pauses my app screen and so it goes black as if everything is at halt which is certainly not the right way to do it.

Please give me a solution as to how to proceed further.

## EDIT

This is executeDisplayQueue() function:

```
@Override
    protected void executeDisplayQueue() throws InterruptedException {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Starting execution of queue...");
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            SomeJob job = null;
            try {
                job = jobShowQueue.take();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Taking Job no. " + job.getId() + " from the queue...");
                if (job.getJobState().equals(JobState.NEW)) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Job state is NEW.");
                    job.setJobState(JobState.RUNNING);
                    job.getCmd().run(bluetoothSocket.getInputStream(), bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream());
                } else {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Job state is not NEW and therefore it should not be in Queue");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ie){
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } catch (UnsupportedCommandException u) {
                if (job != null)
                    job.setJobState(JobState.NOT_SUPPORTED);

            } catch (IOException ioe){
                job.setJobState(JobState.BROKEN_PIPE);

                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Broken Pipe Error. Close the connection and restart again: "+ioe.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e){
                job.setJobState(JobState.EXECUTION_ERROR);
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to run Command. Error: "+e.getMessage());
            }
            if (job != null){
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Job is Finished.");
                final SomeJob finalJob = job;
                ((Activity) applicationContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ((Activity) applicationContext).stateUpdate(finalJob);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically I am taking jobs from the queue one by one and populating it in the activity. So when my activity closes I want this thread (displayThread) to stop as it no longer requires to populate anything. And when it opens again my displayThread should restarts itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a thread lock. Is there a while loop in the method "executeDisplayQueue"? You should probably put the if(){lock.wait()} in the while loop there.

```
private final Object displayThreadLock = new Object();
private boolean mIsBound;

Thread displayThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized(displayThreadLock) {
                if (!mIsBound) {
                    displayThreadLock.wait(); // this thread will wait here util displayThreadLock.notify() is called
                }
                try {
                    executeDisplayQueue();
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    displayThread.interrupt();
                }
            }
        }
});

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    super.onUnbind(intent);
    // Stop/Pause/Wait my displayThread here
    mIsBound = false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    super.onRebind(intent);
    // Restart/Resume my displayThread here
    mIsBound = true;
    synchronized(displayThreadLock) {
        displayThreadLock.notify(); // call notify to break the wait, so the displayThread continues to run
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "trying to check display thread");
}
```

Comment: When I am using the above method, I am getting an error when `displayThreadLock.notify();` is called in `onRebind(Intent intent)`
Here is the error: 
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind to service com.zymbia.app4.services.SomeService@2c0e85b4 with Intent { cmp=com.zymbia.app4/.services.SomeService }: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()`

Comment: No It is working fine. I just changed in onRebind() : `synchronized (displayThreadLock){
            displayThreadLock.notify();
        }`
And now its working completely fine. Thank you so much @wrkwrk for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a try-catch block for InterruptedException in your displayThread, you can stop the thread via:

```
displayThread.interrupt();
```

and just start the displayThread again when rebinding:

```
displayThread.start();
```

By the way, can you show the method body of executeDisplayQueue()? I need to know if this is safe in your case.

There's an extra issue you need to take care of. After the displayThread gets interrupted, which means your activity is not existing anymore, you can't schedule a job to it.

Comment: Above method was deprecated by Google.

Comment: @AnggrayudiH I only know that Thread.stop() and Thread.resume() are deprecated, but Thread.interrupt() should be fine. Where did you read that above method was deprecated?

Comment: If you have the latest documentation from Android 6.0 and you set the target & compile SDK to API 23, you can see that interrupt() method was deprecated.

Comment: Haven't tried with 6.0 yet, let me have a look. Thanks.

Comment: OMG, you are right, `interrupt()` method is not deprecated!

Comment: @t-benze I have edited my question and added the executeDisplayQueue() function. You can have a look. The solution which you said will this not freeze the UI???

Comment: @AnggrayudiH :-) then the world is not insane

Comment: @AND_SUN No, it shouldn't. You can have a try to see if it works.

Comment: @AND_SUN After a second thought, the join() will probably block you ui. We shouldn't use it here.

Comment: When I use the above mentioned method. 
That is onUnbind:
`displayThread.interrupt();`
And in rebind:
`displayThread.start();`

It shows me Java exception that the Thread already started.

Comment: @AND_SUN in onRebind(), just call displayThread.start() again.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but I got the solution in above answer by @wrkwrk. Still thanks for your efforts. Really appreciate it!!!